# How do I control access to the Chrome address bar?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

[image]

I want to make similar chrome address bar calculator.

but I didn't know How to access Chrome address bar from using chrome-extension

1. How to get chrome address bar value

   not url, I want to get new value (ex, 3 + 4 at picture)
2. How to print from recommend bar at the bottom of the address bar

   like caculator result

Thank you in advance for your answer

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox, maybe?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/omnibox

Comment: It doesn't look like you can do it from a web page, only with extensions that the user has to install.